# How to use computational results of a CSV as search terms in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

First off, in my real situation I handel much bigger data sets, but here for this minimal, reproducible example (reprex) let's assume:

I have two .csv files. They look like this:
File 1 is called "ObjectList.csv"

```
"Object","ProductName","ID"
"Radio","ICF-306",1112
"TV","Q60R",1113
"Computer","EliteBook745",1114
"Keyboard","LX410",1115
"Camera","D7500",1116
"USB-Stick","CruzerBlade",1117
"HDMI-Cable","AmazonBasic",1118
"Console","XBOXOne",1119
"Controller","XBOXOne",1120
"Antivirus","AntiVirusPlus",1121
"Game","HaloWars2",1122
```

File 2 is called "PropertyList.csv

```
"ID","Manufacturer","Category","Price","Release"
1112,"SONY","Electronics",50,"1.3.2015"
1113,"SAMSUNG","Electronics",800,"1.7.2016"
1114,"HP","Electronics",1500,"1.3.2018"
1115,"FUJITSU","Electronics","80","1.2.2016"
1116,"NIKON","Electronics","250","1.8.2017"
1117,"SANDISK","Accessories","20","1.6.2007"
1118,"AMAZON","Cables",15,"1.8.2015"
1119,"MICROSOFT","Entertainment",450,"22.11.2013"
1120,"MICROSOFT","Entertainment",50,"22.11.2013"
1121,"NORTON","Programme",100,"1.8.2016"
1122,"MicrosoftStudios","Programme",70,"21.2.2017"
```

As you can see the two .csv files have one column with overlapping information, the "ID" column.
What I would like to do is
1. search for a specific property in file 2 (for example the most expensive product)
2. getting back the "ID" as the search result
3. use the computationally optained "ID" as a search term for file 1 to
4. as a final result get the clear object data.

So far I was able to do this manually, meaning I have a Python/Pandas script that extracts the IDs, then I manually have to look up the result and hard code the result into the script:

```py
import pandas as pd

ObjectList="/media/jk/DE88159688156E71/Statistik/StackOverflow/ObjectList.csv"
PropertyList="/media/jk/DE88159688156E71/Statistik/StackOverflow/PropertyList.csv"

OL = pd.read_csv(ObjectList)
PL = pd.read_csv(PropertyList)

SN = PL[PL['Price']==PL['Price'].max()]['ID']
print(SN)

print(OL[OL.ID == 1114])
```

This script works and gives this result:

```sh
jk@debian:~$ python3 "/media/jk/DE88159688156E71/Statistik/StackOverflow/DataManipulation.py" 
2    1114
Name: ID, dtype: int64
     Object   ProductName    ID
2  Computer  EliteBook745  1114
```

Having to do manual look ups for computational results is bad for obvious reasons. Therefore my question is:
How to use the search result from one .csv file as a search term for a second .csv file?

I tried this:

```
print(OL[OL['ID'] == SN])
```

But this just gives me an error.

Final remark: What I can NOT do in my real scenario is merging of the two files because they are too big for such an operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the values of the series like: `SN.values`
In your example:

```
import pandas as pd

OL = pd.read_csv('ol.csv')
PL = pd.read_csv('pl.csv')

SN = PL[PL['Price']==PL['Price'].max()]['ID']

print(OL[OL.ID == SN.values[0]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This solution worked here for the reprex and also for my real, bigger dataset - thanks!